# VAE generates blue images

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to train a VAE to generates celebA faces.

- **The problem** I'm facing is that the model only generates blue faces and I'm not sure why and how to fix it.

[image: blue faces]

**The encoder:**

```
    def build_encoder(self):

        conv_filters = [32, 64, 64, 64]
        conv_kernel_size = [3, 3, 3, 3]
        conv_strides = [2, 2, 2, 2]

        # Number of Conv layers
        n_layers = len(conv_filters)

        # Define model input
        x = self.encoder_input

        # Add convolutional layers
        for i in range(n_layers):
            x = Conv2D(filters=conv_filters[i],
                       kernel_size=conv_kernel_size[i],
                       strides=conv_strides[i],
                       padding='same',
                       name='encoder_conv_' + str(i)
                       )(x)
            if self.use_batch_norm: # True
                x = BatchNormalization()(x)

            x = LeakyReLU()(x)

            if self.use_dropout: # False
                x = Dropout(rate=0.25)(x)

        # Required for reshaping latent vector while building Decoder
        self.shape_before_flattening = K.int_shape(x)[1:]

        x = Flatten()(x)

        self.mean_layer = Dense(self.encoder_output_dim, name='mu')(x)
        self.sd_layer = Dense(self.encoder_output_dim, name='log_var')(x)

        # Defining a function for sampling
        def sampling(args):
            mean_mu, log_var = args
            epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(mean_mu), mean=0., stddev=1.)
            return mean_mu + K.exp(log_var / 2) * epsilon

            # Using a Keras Lambda Layer to include the sampling function as a layer

        # in the model
        encoder_output = Lambda(sampling, name='encoder_output')([self.mean_layer, self.sd_layer])

        return Model(self.encoder_input, encoder_output, name="VAE_Encoder")
```

**The decoder:**

```
def build_decoder(self):
    conv_filters = [64, 64, 32, 3]
    conv_kernel_size = [3, 3, 3, 3]
    conv_strides = [2, 2, 2, 2]

    n_layers = len(conv_filters)

    # Define model input
    decoder_input = self.decoder_input

    # To get an exact mirror image of the encoder
    x = Dense(np.prod(self.shape_before_flattening))(decoder_input)
    x = Reshape(self.shape_before_flattening)(x)

    # Add convolutional layers
    for i in range(n_layers):
        x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=conv_filters[i],
                            kernel_size=conv_kernel_size[i],
                            strides=conv_strides[i],
                            padding='same',
                            name='decoder_conv_' + str(i)
                            )(x)

        # Adding a sigmoid layer at the end to restrict the outputs
        # between 0 and 1
        if i < n_layers - 1:
            x = LeakyReLU()(x)
        else:
            x = Activation('sigmoid')(x)

    # Define model output
    self.decoder_output = x

    return Model(decoder_input, self.decoder_output, name="VAE_Decoder")
```

**The combined model:**

```
def build_autoencoder(self):
    self.encoder = self.build_encoder()
    self.decoder = self.build_decoder()

    # Input to the combined model will be the input to the encoder.
    # Output of the combined model will be the output of the decoder.
    self.autoencoder = Model(self.encoder_input, self.decoder(self.encoder(self.encoder_input)),
                             name="Variational_Auto_Encoder")

    self.autoencoder.compile(optimizer=self.adam_optimizer, loss=self.total_loss,
                             metrics=[self.total_loss],
                             experimental_run_tf_function=False)
    self.autoencoder.summary()
```

**The loss function:**

```
def r_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=[1, 2, 3])

def kl_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
    kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + self.sd_layer - K.square(self.mean_layer) - K.exp(self.sd_layer), axis=1)
    return kl_loss

def total_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
    # return self.LOSS_FACTOR * self.r_loss(y_true, y_pred) + self.kl_loss(y_true, y_pred)
    return K.mean(self.r_loss(y_true, y_pred) + self.kl_loss(y_true, y_pred))
```

Comment: You should look into your data loader. It is most likely that you are using OpenCV to load the images, hence the images are being loaded in BGR format, rather than RGB format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to @SalvadorMedina's comment** I fixed this embarrassing problem.

the generated image was good but I used OpenCV to save and show it and defaulted to **BRG mode instead of RGB**.

To fix the problem I added the line:

```
im_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(im_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

and now it looks like that:

[image: Fixed image here]

Note: 
this problem can be solved without `cvtColor()`, these should work as well:

- `im_rgb = im_bgr[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]`
- `im_rgb = im_bgr[:, :, ::-1]`